# select number between certain words in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question regarding extracting numeric information from text in SQL.
The "shop_priceChange" sheet looks like this:

```
shop_id    apply_content
10048586    {"priceChange":"item price change from 88.0 to 98.0"}
10050114    {"priceChange":package price change from 0.8 to 1.0"}
10036306    {"priceChange":"item price change from 19.0 to 21.0"}
```

I hope to get below table by extracting before/after price information from "shop_priceChange" sheet:

```
shop_id    category    before    after
10048586    item        88        98
10050114    package     0.8       1.0
10036306    item       19.0       21.0
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What database do you use ? Will the format of the column "apply_content" always be the same like you have shown (item example and package example)?

Comment: Thank you everyone. The DBMS is Postgre.

Comment: @Sean.H , one more thing. Please, when people answer you and when you find the correct answer among them do mark them as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what DBMS you are using, but assuming a string pattern of `"priceChange":"XXX price change from YYY to ZZZ"`, you can try something like this on `Postgres`:

```sql
SELECT shop_id,
  SUBSTRING(apply_content, 'priceChange":"(\w+)') category,
  SUBSTRING(apply_content, 'price change from ([0-9][\.\d]*) to') price_before,
  SUBSTRING(apply_content, 'price change from.*to ([0-9][\.\d]*)') price_after
FROM my_table
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/41921)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is Postgres, you can convert your text column to jsonb like this:

```
select shop_id
       , split_part(apply_content::jsonb->>'priceChange', ' '::text, 1) as category
       , split_part(apply_content::jsonb->>'priceChange', ' '::text, 5) as before
       , split_part(apply_content::jsonb->>'priceChange', ' '::text, 7) as after 
from shop_priceChange;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which DBMS you are using, I have proposed my solution using `SQL Srever`

**[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e138faea683581af3517710423e56f0b)**

Use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`

```
SELECT shop_id,SUBSTRING(apply_content, CHARINDEX(':"',apply_content)+2, CHARINDEX('price',apply_content, CHARINDEX('price',apply_content)+1) - CHARINDEX(':"',apply_content)-2) as Categoty
  ,SUBSTRING(apply_content, CHARINDEX('from',apply_content) + 4, CHARINDEX('to',apply_content) - CHARINDEX('from',apply_content) - 4) as [Before]
  ,SUBSTRING(apply_content, CHARINDEX('to',apply_content), CHARINDEX('"}',apply_content) - CHARINDEX('to',apply_content)) as [After]
FROM tbl
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh Updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share `regexp_substr` from `mysql` on dealing this requirement.

```
select shop_id, case when apply_content like '%item%' then 'item'
    when apply_content like '%package%' then 'package' else '' end as category    
    , regexp_substr(apply_content, '([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)') as `before`
    , replace(regexp_substr(
        regexp_substr(apply_content, '([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+).+'), 'to ([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)') 
        , 'to ', '') as `after`
from test
```

Here's the [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWif2AAexHAVMFKzxjYeoz/0#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH    SEAN_H_TEST_DATA    AS

(

SELECT  1 AS  primary_key ,    10048586  AS  shop_id     ,    '{"priceChange":"item price change from 88.0 to 98.0"}'  AS  apply_content   UNION
SELECT  2,   10050114   ,     '{"priceChange":package price change from 0.8 to 1.0"}'     UNION
SELECT  3,  10036306   ,    '{"priceChange":"item price change from 19.0 to 21.0"}'

)



SELECT primary_key ,  shop_id  ,   apply_content     ,

REGEXP_SUBSTR(apply_content ,  'item|package'  )   AS  category    ,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(apply_content  ,   '[[:digit:]]+.0|0.[[:digit:]]'  )   AS   before      ,
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(apply_content  ,   '( to )([[:digit:]]+.0|0.[[:digit:]])'    ) ,  ' to ', '')   AS   after 

FROM   SEAN_H_TEST_DATA

ORDER BY 1
```